# RedirectStandardOutput prevents Process.Exited event raised?

Tags: c#, process

All I want is to redirect standard output of a process to a file. Sounds easy, but everything I tried doesn't work:

1. putting a DOS-style redirection in the list of arguments (e.g. `param1 param2 > output.txt`) doesn't work;
2. using `RedirectStandardOutput = true` works, BUT, apparently the process does not raise an event when it exists. So the handler defined via `process.Exited += ...`  doesn't execute. To be clear, once I remove the `RedirectStandardOutput = true` statement, it DOES raise an event.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do exceptions have to do with exiting a process? Are you relying on an exception being thrown to know when to stop the process?

Comment: Once you enable `RedirectStandardXXX` you are responsible for pumping that source, otherwise the process "suspends" since it's buffers are full.  Where do you think all that output goes?  It goes to you; you must read it!

Answer (score 1):

Method #2 must be the way to go.
The problem seems to be caused by output buffering which prevents triggering `Exited` event.

You should consider eliminating the `Exited` event handler. Instead, subscribe to `OutputDataReceived` event and check `Process.HasExited` property in the handler to perform cleanup job:

```
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);

...

void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Process p = (Process) sender;
    if(p.HasExited) ...
}
```

Comment: Output buffering doesn't prevent `Exited` from being triggered, the fact that you are not pumping the Standard Output has the process "paused" because it cannot write any more output.  Once you start reading the Standard Output, everything works correctly.  You can do both; you do not have to "give up" on the Exited event!